# Adding to a dictionary's subdictionary in Python, based off a subdictionary's key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
test = {1: {'los angeles': ['playlist1', 'playlist2']}, 2: {'houston': ['playlist']}}
```

In this code, I want to add to the array belonging to 'los angeles', basically appending to it. Is there a way to perform an action where 1 is declared like a wildcard? I wanted to do something like this:

```
test[_]['los angeles'].append('playlist3')
```

Which would result in:

```
test = {1: {'los angeles': ['playlist1', 'playlist2', 'playlist3']}, 2: {'houston': ['playlist']}}
```

Comment: Could you clarify abit more on what you mean by 1 being declared like a wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I completely understand the question but if I may give it a try.

The integer keys in the outer dict seem to be what's holding you up.

It seems you have some data set of **city names** and you want to map those strings to two other data sets, **city numbers** and **city playlists**.

Instead of doing it all in one multidimensional dict, you can just use separate dicts for separate mappings.

```
city_playlists = {'los angeles':['playlist1', 'playlist2'],
                  'houston':['playlist']}
city_names = {1:'los angeles',
              2:'houston'}
```

Then data retrieval and updating is much more straightforward.

```
city_playlists['los angeles'].append('playlist3')
```

And if I understand what you mean by 'wildcard'

```
wildcard = random.randint(1, len(city_names))
name = city_names[wildcard]
city_playlists[name].append('newplaylist')
```

You could also use a list for mapping **city numbers** to **city names** as lists have indexing, then use `random.choice` to pull out a random city name from the list.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such wildcard-like thing. You should do it manually:

```
for k in test:
    if 'los angeles' in test[k]:
        test[k]['los angeles'].append('playlist3')
```

Or:

```
test[next(k for k in test if 'los angeles' in test[k])]['los angeles'].append('playlist3')
```

One-liner version will throw StopIteration if there's no dictionary with 'log angeles' key. And it only update the first dictionary that matched.